# How do I align an `outside` bullet list item to the margin of the page?

Tags: html, css

I have a list with a custom bullet type:
[image]

This works exactly how I want. The list item's text wraps without going under the custom bullet, the bullet is aligned with the rest of the page, etc. What I'm not happy with is that I've accomplished this using a hard-coded padding value:

```html
<ul style= "list-style-position:outside;padding-left:86.3167px;">
    <!-- list item -->
</ul>
```

Is there a way to accomplish this without having the hard-coded value?

Full example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Cool Website</title>
    <style>
         html {
             font-family: sans-serif;
         }

         body {
             margin: 0;
             padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
             line-height: 1.4em;
             margin-left: auto;
             margin-right: auto;
         }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>My Cool Website</h1>
    </div>
    <ul style=
    "list-style-position:outside;padding-left:86.3167px;">
        <li style="list-style-type:'2022-04-18 ';">
            <a href=
            "/blog/my-long-blog-post-title-that-spans-two-lines-on-my-blog-site">
            my long blog post title that spans two lines on my blog
            site</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried an `inside` style but that puts the wrapped text under the bullet item:
[image]

```
<ul style="list-style-position:inside;padding-left:0;">
    <!-- list item -->
</ul>
```

Comment: Couple thoughts: accessibility. Is the date read to users with screen readers? Another way to look at it: tabular data -> `<table>`.

Comment: @stealththeninja Great point! I was definitely too focused on the list styling. Looks great with the table. Will make an answer including that, thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

You should change the value of list-style-position css property from outside to inside, and it will work.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I tried this. This doesn't exactly fit my requirements because it causes the text to go under the bullet item. Edited post to add that.

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to @stealththeninja for recommending I use a table, here's what I did:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>2022-04-18</td>
        <td>
            <a href=
            "/blog/my-long-blog-post-title-that-spans-two-lines-on-my-blog-site">
            my long blog post title that spans two lines on my
            blog site</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I added this to `<style>`:

```
td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Looks great!
[image]